# Highcharts resize doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I'm am using a framework called JDASH to draw floating user controls (which are actually update panels) and in them I am drawing highcharts.
For some reason, sometimes when the update panel resizes, highcharts fails to resize in it.
I tried calling resize:

```
var chartName = '<%= GetChartName() %>';
    $("#" + chartName.toString() + "_container").resize(function (e) {      
        //chartName.redraw();
    });
```

This helps in some cases, but in other cases this function is not called.
Any idea on how to force highcharts to redraw?

Thanks,
Omer

Comment: Is there an option to see this live? I mean that error when charts isn't rescaled.

Comment: @PawełFus, is there any way I can send you the link privaetly? also we see that inside the update panel the chart will not add new dada even if redraw is called and even on full page refresh. we get the same chart over and over again until we clear the cache. this happens in chrome and explorer 9 and I'll be very thankeful for any insight

Comment: Send mail to support@highcharts.com with that link and point to this topic. We will look into this tomorrow.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? We're trying the same thing with the same 2 libraries :) To be specific; we can't get this working when clicking the maximize button that JDash provides.

Answer (score 1):

```
chart.series[0].setData(data,true);
```

The `setData` method itself will call the `redraw` method

Comment: I can catch the resize eventof the user control, but this is done in javascript code in the master page. from there I can't call GetChartName so I don't know how to gain access to the specific chart inside my user control.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue when the JDASH element its maximize button was clicked and fixed it with this:

**The JDash element its View:**

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**The javascript of the JDash element:**

```
resize: function (event) {
      var container = $('.dashlet' + event.sender.id).find("#container");
      var chart = $(container).highcharts();

      chart.reflow();
}
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.

For the sake of completeness; it could be that you drag & drop your dashlet to a smaller or larger zone, which should also resize the chart. If so you'll need this code:

```
resize: function (event) {
    if (!event) { return true; }
    if (!event.sender) { return true; }

    var containerId;

    if (event.sender.id == "DDML_0") { // A dashlet container gets this class when it is being dragged.
        containerId = $(".dashlet" + event.args.pane.context.id);
    } else {
        containerId = $('.dashlet' + event.sender.id);
    }

    var container = $(containerId).find("#container");
    var chart = $(container).highcharts();

    if (!chart) { return true; }

    chart.reflow();
```

}